# Why does my volumetric light disappear when I disable camera visibility?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, volumetrics

I have been playing around with volumetric lighting and wanted to make a basic render. I create a point light put a UV sphere around it and deleted some of the faces to get the volumetric light. However the cube for which I'm using to control the volume scatter is still visible. I went an unchecked the Camera for ray visibility but the moment I do that my volumetric light disappears. Any suggestions?

With camera turned on:
[image: With camera turned on]

With camera turned off:
[image: With camera turned off]

Comment: please post an image of the nodes for the cube. For volumetrics you need noting connected to the surface socket, only the volume socket shoud be used.

Answer (score 1):

Disabling camera ray visibility prevents an object or shader from being evaluated until after a ray has bounced for the first time. Directly visible volumetric light comes from striking the volume on the first hit. By disabling camera ray visibility, you prevent this interaction since there is no first hit on the volume.

What exactly are you trying to accomplish? I'm not seeing anything wrong with your first image.

Btw, you may get somewhat improved performance by using an emission texture on your light itself instead of enclosing it in a sphere with holes. The texture will prevent sampling around the solid areas of the sphere. Use the texture coordinate > normal output to mapping on a point light.

Comment: in the first image it's hard to tell but the cube it'self is still visible. Preventing me from using a world texture.

Comment: World texture should still be visible through volumes, provided the scattering doesn't wash it out. Just make sure the cube doesn't have corners/edges visible within the camera frame.

Comment: the edges arent visible however the world texture doesn't show through the cube.

Comment: Do you have any surface shaders on the volume material? If so, get rid of them. Otherwise, that sound like the scattered light just overwhelming the background.